# Windows 7 not recognizing printer for driver (re)installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

A user deleted her printer. She is using a HP Deskjet 6940 printer, and for her desktop she has a HP dx2400, with Windows 7.

After I plug in the USB cable it should install the new drivers, but it isn't.

Why isn't Windows 7 recognizing the printer so that the driver can be reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the printer but probably didn't delete the drivers. Have the user go into the Devices and Printers control panel applet, select any printer that's listed (if none are listed then add a generic printer and select it), then select the Print server properties item on the tool bar, click the drivers tab, find and remove the driver for the printer you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the system. Windows 7 should prompt for the printer again, else pop in the printer driver disc(download the latest drivers) and install the drivers.